# Microsoft Excel calculating the wrong time and date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an interesting question for you. I have a formula in [Date and Time] Column

IF([@Courier]<>"",IF([@[Date and Time]]="",NOW(),[@[Date and Time]]),"")

The idea of this formula is to input a date and time when [Courier] is populated.

However, every once in a while, not all the time, I get a date and time from the past, it typically doesn't happen right away.

For example right now, one of the cells in [Date and Time] reads, "1/0/1900 0:00" and the next 4 cells are, "4/16/2019 12:10" 2 hours before the information was entered in [Courier]

I know this is a circular reference, so I have iterative calculations set at 1

Comment: You’re showing us a formula that uses column names (“Courier” and “Date and Time”) and then asking us questions about Column ``B``.  Please choose apples or oranges, not both.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: When I tried recreating the situation, it's behaving very strange indeed. Do you get the same problem when using `IF(B2<>"",IF(A2="",NOW(),A2,"")` and copying down? Not that we get same problem, so might not be that. By the way `[@[Date and Time]]` seems very strange I can't even do that, it automatically reverts to `[@Date and Time]`.

Comment: The cells are formatted as a table so the formula picks up the location automatically. It's essentially the same formula you have listed, just using different cell names. The interesting thing is that it works 90% of the time with no issue, but every once in a while is messes with the time.

Comment: In case you're not aware, Excel stores dates as a day count since Jan 0, 1900 (1/1/1900 = day 1), and times as decimal fraction of a day.  So a cell value of zero or an empty cell will display as "1/0/1900 0:00" when formatted as a date/time.  Also, you can limit the damage from circular references by controlling iterations, but you can still get weird results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterative calculations can be messy for this, and not always work the way you expect.

It would be more robust to use a VBA event-triggered macro.

The below macro duplicates your formula and will clear the time if you clear the contents of `Courier`.  It will enter the time when you enter contents into `Courier`.

Note that, as it appears from your formula, it will NOT change the time if you change the contents of `Courier` from `a` to `b`.  *(That could be done with some additional code)*.

The code assumes

- there is only a single table on the worksheet. *If there are more, the code would need to be changed*
- `Courier` is the **first** column of that table
- `Date and Time` is directly **adjacent** to `Courier` (i.e. the second column of the table)

To enter this event-triggered Macro, right click on the sheet tab.
Select "View Code" from the right-click drop-down menu.
Then paste the code below into the window that opens.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim LO As ListObject
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
Set LO = ListObjects(1)

Set R = Intersect(Target, LO.DataBodyRange.Columns(1))
If Not R Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each C In R
        Select Case C.Value
            Case ""
                C.ClearContents
                C.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            Case Else
                Select Case C.Offset(0, 1)
                    Case ""
                        C.Offset(0, 1) = Date + Time
                End Select
        End Select
    Next C
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Heres a follow up for this, I don't understand VBA well enough to figure this out, but here goes.Based on the outcome of the code above, I get a time and date in "date and Time" column. This time and date is used to calculate a "Slotted Delevery Time" in another column. For example if the current time is before 9am then the slotted delivery time is 9am. If, howerver it is between 9 and noon, the deliverytime should read noon. etc.. How would I add that functionality to the VBA code?

Comment: @sdderksen I guess you figured out how to alter the `Columns` and `Offset` to refer to the proper columns.  For this new problem, although the VBA code could be altered, I would just populate that column with a formula that does what you describe.  No need for VBA in that scenario.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to write that into VBA is partially for education and partially for security. The formula can be cumbersome and if I allow others to use the sheet and they mess it up, It causes pain. I can lock the cells, but I'm having issues with using a macro and locking the cells. Really I'd like to see the difference in the coding to learn more. I think I've started to understand the Code above, or at least started to.

Comment: Your question is really too broad, and lacking sufficient information, to be answered in a comment. You could add the functionality and write the result to the desired column.  But dealing with the specifics probably merits a new question. And when you do that, be sure to provide sufficient information that a respondent can easily reproduce your problem.  As well as your own attempt to solve the problem and where you ran into trouble. The latter, especially, will attract the most useful type of assistance.